# How to modulate params from a Web Audio Api ScriptProcessor?

Tags: web-audio-api, scriptprocessor

I am working on a Browser Synth with the Web Audio Api.
Instead of using the "build in" OscillatorNode I want to develop a custom Oscillator model via the ScriptProcessorNode. 
I am able to modulate the AudioParams of the "Build in" nodes with other nodes.

How can I connect internal Params of the ProcessorNode to other AudioNodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean "how do I create AudioParam members of a ScriptProcessorNode that I can connect other sources to, to modulate my ScriptProcessor" - the short answer is, today you can't.  It probably will not be in version 1 of Web Audio: https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/134.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I meant, although I hoped for an other answer.

Comment: The API writes something about an AudioProcessingEvent which is "dispatched to ScriptProcessorNode node". I thought there might be a way to build an envelope follower and submit the values to the ScriptProcessor.
But clearly some smarter guys than me have to do this ...