# Change duty cycle in AudioContext

Tags: javascript, frequency, audiocontext

I'm trying to play a frequency with a different duty cycle than the default (0.5).

Here they just mentioned the issue
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OscillatorNode/type

And there is no information how to do it

```js
function beep() {
    const audioCtx = new AudioContext();
    const oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();

    oscillator.type = 'square';
    oscillator.frequency.setValueAtTime(440, audioCtx.currentTime);
    oscillator.start();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="beep()">beep</button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modulate the pulsewidth of the Web Audio API Square OscillatorNode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178908/how-to-modulate-the-pulsewidth-of-the-web-audio-api-square-oscillatornode)